# how to change a variable to equal somehting else using conditional statements, python, pyscripter

Tags: python

I want to code for: if cc is negative, then cc should become 0. cc is a variable. how do I do that?
the code inserted is only a section of my code.

```
if cc <0 :
    then cc == 0
    print("The skill you have inputted is negative, it will stored as 0")

elif dd <0 :
    then dd == 0
    print ("The skill you have inputted is negative, it will be stored as 0")

else :
    print ("Don't worry nothing has changed!")
```

is this correct now???

```
if cc <0 or dd <0:
    cc == 0
    dd ==0
    print("The skill you have inputted is negative, it will stored as 0")

else :
    print ("Don't worry nothing has changed!")

if c==0 or d==0:
    print("The strength you inputted is 0. Your character dies.")

elif c<0 or d<0:
    print("The strength you have inputted is negative. Your character dies.")

else :
    print ("Don't worry nothing has changed!")
```

Comment: So if `cc` is bigger than 0, it doesn't matter which value `dd` has?

Comment: dd is the same, if dd is negative then dd should become 0

Comment: Then you shouldn't be putting that condition into an `elif` clause...

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the variable to a new value with `=`:

```
if cc < 0:
    cc = 0
    print("The skill you have inputted is negative, it will stored as 0")

elif dd < 0:
    dd = 0
    print("The skill you have inputted is negative, it will be stored as 0")

else:
    print("Don't worry nothing has changed!")
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> cc = -1
>>> if cc < 0:
...     cc = 0
...
>>> cc
0
>>>
```

---

However, your code looks like it has a logic error too.  If `cc` is greater than zero, `dd` will never be checked because you used `elif`.

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
if cc < 0 or dd < 0:  # See if cc or dd is less than 0

    if cc < 0:  # See if cc is less than 0
        cc = 0  # Assign cc to 0
        print("The skill you have inputted is negative, it will stored as 0")

    if dd < 0:  # See if dd is less than 0
        dd = 0  # Assign dd to 0
        print("The skill you have inputted is negative, it will stored as 0")

else:  # If we get here, then neither cc nor dd was less than 0
    print("Don't worry nothing has changed!")
```

Comment: very true, changed it, thank you so much for your help (: it is so annoying when you don't understand a code error!!!

Comment: @user3569687 - No, you need to use `=` for variable assignment.  `==` is for comparison tests.  You should look at the code I gave at the bottom of my answer.  I believe it does everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
cc = max(0, cc)
```

and avoid the `if` statement altogether.